# Copy usermeta value where ID matches in the same table

Tags: mysql, user-meta

I would like to copy the meta_value from row to another (in the same table) where the user_id matches.

Each user in the `wp_usermeta` table has a `meta_key`/`meta_value` pair for `first_name` and a `meta_key`/`meta_value` pair for `shipping_first_name`. I would like to copy the `shipping_first_name` value to the `first_name` value where the `user_id` matches. I would like to update all users in the database at once (e.g., via phpMyAdmin).

How should this MySQL query be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code, it may help you

```
 $users = get_users($args);
      if($users) {
        foreach($users as $user) {
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            $shipping_first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_first_name', true);
                if($shipping_first_name) {
                  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $shipping_first_name);  
                }
            }
        }
```

for $args - refer link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to execute a update query in order to update all users at once. Wouldn't you answer only update the currently logged-in user? Sorry that I was not more detailed with my question. I'll update it to be clearer.

Comment: I have updated code, please check if it will help :)

Comment: I used `'role' => 'Customer'` for the $args and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Sounds Great it is working fine for you. Cheers :)